How to progressively accelerate video and audio with FFmpeg?
As suggested in this other question, we can progressively change playback speed with ffmpeg using setpts filter:
ffmpeg -y -i Video15sec30fps.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=(0.5+N/450)*PTS" out.mp4

I tried usingasetpts, atempo, asetrate, aresample filters with no luck to sync audio and video.
I can do this with Adobe After Effects and make a good ramped slow motion with audio and video, but I wish to automatize this task using FFmpeg (or any Linux software).
Any idea how to make a sync audio with asetpts=f(N)*PTS or any other way?

N → is number of consumed samples for audio, so try this → ffmpeg -y -i Video15sec30fps.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=(0.5+N/30/15)*PTS" -filter:a "asetpts=(0.5+N/48000/15)*PTS" out.mp4 where 30 is fps and 48000 is sample rate

It works, but when the audio drops below 1x the sound is discontinuous. But this can be fixed if I do an audio pre-encoding with the lowest speed, then apply the ramp...

mpv warns at ~11 sec → Audio/Video desynchronisation detected! maybe, variable sample rate doesn't work. as variant, split audio to many parts, use atempo or rubberband to every part to change speed and concat results

Worked for me splitting in parts and set septs=X*PTS for video and resample=samplerate/X,resample=samplerate for audio in every part, then concatenate all in one video with audio.

tried to split audio and use rubberband
#!/bin/bash
f="/some/videos/unfzfe8f9NI.mkv"
ffmpeg -to 25 -i "$f" -map 0:a:0 -c:a pcm_s16le -f segment -segment_time 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -map_metadata -1 %04d.mkv -v error -stats
LST=(*.mkv)
rm /tmp/1.txt
CNT=0.5
CN2=2
DU2=0
TST=0
for g in ${LST[@]}; do
  DUR=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of csv=p=0 "$g")
  DU2=$(echo "$DU2 + $DUR" | bc -l)
  echo "---------> $g → $DUR → $DU2 → $CN2 → $TST"

  ffmpeg -i "$g" -af "rubberband=tempo=$CN2" -c:a pcm_s16le "/tmp/$g.mkv" -y -v error -stats
  echo "file '$g.mkv'" >> /tmp/1.txt

  CN2=$(echo "1 / ($CNT + $DU2 / 15 * 2.06)" | bc -l)
  TST=$(echo "$CNT + $DU2 / 15" | bc -l)
done

ffmpeg -to 25 -i "$f" -f concat -safe 0 -i /tmp/1.txt -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -vf "
setpts=(0.5+N/FR/15)*PTS" -c:v ffv1 -c:a copy /tmp/out.mkv -y -v error -stats
#check durations, if not equal change 2.06 value
ffprobe -hide_banner /tmp/out.mkv
ffplay /tmp/out.mkv

2.06 is some idk what is this. it depends from idk from what. check durations of output streams
